# I deleted Teams' default background images, but why do they still appear?

Tags: microsoft-teams

[image]

I'm using Teams on my personal Windows desktop. I followed the steps below and deleted all such images, but why do I still see these images on Teams?

[How to Delete Background from Microsoft Teams View? - Appuals.com](https://appuals.com/delete-background-from-microsoft-teams-view/)

> Additionally, you can also delete the native backgrounds in the MS Teams view in a similar fashion but the location address will be different in this regard. Follow these steps to do this:
>
> 1. Press **Windows + R** keys together to launch the Run dialog box. It is a Windows tool that is generally used to navigate to hidden system directories.
> 2. Copy-paste the following location address in the search bar and press **Enter**. This will take you to MS Teams Backgrounds hidden folder.
>
>    %AppData%\Microsoft\Teams\Backgrounds
>
>    [image]
>
>    Opening MS Teams Backgrounds Folder
> 3. Delete the **built-in photos** that you no longer want to use as the background. Once done, close File Explorer.
> 4. Launch MS Teams application. The background should now be the default.

Comment: Is this a personal or corporate machine. Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound Done.

Comment: Regarding step 4, are you sure you quit Teams before re-opening it? Did you close it from the taskbar tray by clicking on Quit?